# How can I shorten these codes with if not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 if not (argument1 and argument2 and argument3).isalpha():
    print(("Argument {} {} {} are not a word. All arguments should be word").format(argument1, argument2, argument3))       
if not (argument1.isalpha() and argument2.isalpha() and argument3.isalpha()):
        print(("Argument {} {} {} are not a word. All arguments should be word").format(argument1, argument2, argument3))
```

**the first code doesn't work but the second one does How can I shorten the second code like first code ?**
***and can you shorten the whole code?***

```
if not (argument1.isalpha() and argument2.isalpha() and argument3.isalpha()):
    print(("Argument {} {} {} are not a word. All arguments should be word").format(argument1, argument2, argument3))
elif not (argument1 and argument2).isalpha():
    print(("Argument {} {} are not a word. All arguments should be word").format(argument1, argument2))
elif not (argument1 and argument3).isalpha():
    print(("Argument {} {} are not a word. All arguments should be word").format(argument1, argument3))
elif not (argument2 and argument3).isalpha():
    print(("Argument {} {} are not a word. All arguments should be word").format(argument2, argument3))
elif not argument1.isalpha():
    print(("Argument {} is not a word. All arguments should be word").format(argument1))
elif not argument2.isalpha():
    print(("Argument {} is not a word. All arguments should be word").format(argument2))
elif not argument3.isalpha():
    print(("Argument {} is not a word. All arguments should be word").format(argument3))
else:
```

**it should continue the code**

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
bad_arguments = []
if not argument1.isalpha():
    bad_arguments.append(argument1)
if not argument2.isalpha():
    bad_arguments.append(argument2)
if not argument3.isalpha():
    bad_arguments.append(argument3)

if len(bad_arguments) == 1:
    print(("Argument {} is not a word. All arguments should be words").format(bad_arguments[0]))
elif len(bad_arguments) > 1:
    print(("Arguments {} are not words. All arguments should be words").format(" ".join(bad_arguments)))
else:
    #all the arguments are words do what you want here
```

or if your arguments are in a list you can shorten the first part:

```
bad_arguments = []
for argument in arguments:
    if not argument.isalpha():
        bad_arguments.append(argument)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is also support integers:

```
for i in [argument1,argument2,argument3]:
    if not (isinstance(i,str) and i.isalpha()):
        print('{} is not word'.format(i))
```

note that if you are using `Python3.6` or higher you can user new form of formatted strings:

```
print(f'{i} is not word')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your arguments into a list and then check if any of them isn't alphabetic and then print which arguments are incorrect.

```
argument1 = 'abc'
argument2 = 'abc 123'
argument3 = '123'
arguments = [argument1, argument2, argument3]
wrong_args = [not i.isalpha() for i in arguments]

if any(wrong_args):
    print('Arguments {} are not alphabetic'.format(' '.join(str(idx+1) for idx, i in enumerate(wrong_args) if i)))
else:
    print('Your arguments are correct')
```

Answer (score 0):

AntiMatterDynamite's answer is good, however this can even be done a bit shorter with lists:

```
argument1, argument2, argument3 = "a", "b", "0123"
listOfArgs = [argument1, argument2, argument3]

# get the list of invalid argumetns
listOfInvalidArgs = [arg for arg in listOfArgs if not arg.isalpha()]
# if the list is not empty
if listOfInvalidArgs:
    print("Argument {} is/are not a word(s). All arguments should be words!".format(" ".join(listOfInvalidArgs)))
```

or shorter

```
if [arg for arg in [argument1, argument2, argument3] if not arg.isalpha()]:
    print("Argument {} is/are not a word(s). All arguments should be word".format(" ".join(listOfInvalidArgs)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it looks like you're simply trying to check if certain string arguments are not alphabetic.

The problem with your short version is that you are not calling `isalpha()` on the strings and instead are performing `and` between your strings. You will see the problem very clearly if you simply print out the result of `(argument1 and argument2 and argument3)`. You will notice the result is not a boolean (like you probably expected) but the value of the last string.

You actually fixed this in the longer code example: `(argument1.isalpha() and ...` instead of on the entire block.

Based on your second code block you also want to identify which of the arguments are wrong. Whilst you could do this for exactly three arguments it would be nicer to create a more generic solution in order to do this with any number of arguments. As a start you could do it like this:

```
def check_alphabetic(*arguments):
    non_alphabetic = []
    for arg in arguments:
        if not arg.isalpha():
            non_alphabetic.append(arg)
    return non_alphabetic
```

You can then simply check if the returned list is empty. If it isn't, you can print your message using all the arguments from the list.

This can be shortened further by using a list comprehension:

```
# assuming arguments is a list
non_alphabetic = [arg for arg in arguments if not arg.isalpha()]
```